# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline - turn off image asset fingerprinting on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Because a jQuery plugin I use in my application has direct references to images, I'm trying to turn off asset fingerprinting.

So I set `config.assets.digest = false` in my production.rb, but now none of my image references work at all. `/assets/foo.png` just returns a blank response.

I really don't want to alter the jQuery plugin's code and add erb image helpers, but I'm not sure what else to do. And frankly, the asset fingerprinting for images seems to be much more trouble than it's worth.

Does anybody have any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you re-precompile your assets? `rake assets:precompile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a large plugin, like ckeditor, then your only real option is to move that plugin into the public directory.

For smaller plugins you can move their images into the correct asset path. For example if your plugin references `images/icon.jpg` under the plugin folder this would need to be moved to something like `app/assets/images/plugin_name/icon.png` and then referenced in the plugin with `<%= asset_tag('plugin_name/icon.png') %>`.

The pipeline IS worth it. Not using digests in production pretty much negates the point of using it at all, which is to set far-future headers so that the asset gets cached somewhere.

If you are set on removing digests then you must precompile the assets (so that Sprockets does not serve them with far-future headers), and make sure no headers are set on the server.

Comment: I just moved the images for the plugin into their own folder in the public directory. This way, I can leave the digests on for all other assets. I do think the asset pipeline is very useful for CSS and Javascript, but I'm still not convinced of its usefulness for images.

Comment: The usefulness for images - especially ones in CSS or that are accessed frequently - is that they get fingerprinted and can thus have far-future headers set. If you do that with a company logo that is on every page, or a sprite of CSS backgrounds, these are going to be cached. Frequent visitors will likely have access to that image locally or at a border cache, saving the download and speeding up their browsing experience.

Answer (score 3):

Someone made a gem for this purpose:

https://github.com/spohlenz/digestion

> The asset pipeline is a great new component of Rails 3.1. However it
>   has a feature known as fingerprinting that makes it impossible to
>   properly incorporate many popular JavaScript libraries (including
>   TinyMCE, CKEditor and FancyZoom to name just a few) into the asset
>   pipeline.
>
> This gem patches the asset pipeline to allow these libraries to be
>   used, by disabling the fingerprinting functionality for specific files
>   or paths.

Comment: Oh that's a great idea. I'll look into this later. Thanks!

Comment: The functionality of that gem has been merged into Rails.

Comment: @Richard Hulse: can you elaborate?

Comment: In Rails 3.1.3+ rails assets are compiled with and without digests, and the helper methods allow you to turn off using the fingerprinted filename in production.