# Removing Image Timestamp from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I stop images from being timestamped in my production environment?

http://example.com/assets/facebook-048d1c29fef2f06316fac3fff8f6ecf5.png

Coming from

```
<%= link_to image_tag("facebook.png", :class => "socialFacebook", :alt => "Facebook"), "http://www.facebook.com", target: "_blank" %>
```

Edit: I want to keep CSS and JavaScript with the timestamps.
I'm on Rails 4.

Thanks!

Comment: do you know why they are timestamped?

Comment: @apneadiving I can take many guesses from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html but I still can't figure out it out.

Comment: It's a fingerprint actually.. Not a timestamp..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline - turn off image asset fingerprinting on Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375810/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-turn-off-image-asset-fingerprinting-on-heroku)

Comment: @Tim Timestamp, fingerprint.. Okay. Thank you. I already knew that but just called it timestamp on here for whatever. The issue still remains. I want to remove FINGERPRINT for images only.

Comment: @Tim Not a duplicate and does not answer my question.

Comment: Check the second answer. Doesn't it answer your question? It says theres a gem that lets you turn off fingerprinting for specific files or paths..

Comment: are you using paperclip ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

A gem: https://github.com/bluetools/fingerprintless

Or use `digest: false` as an option to `asset_path` within `image_tag`

```
<%= image_tag asset_path('filename.png', digest: false) %>
```

Found it right here:

[Rails 3.1 Use an image without fingerprint hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299724/rails-3-1-use-an-image-without-fingerprint-hash)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Paperclip you can globally default them to off:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:use_timestamp] = false
```

If you want to remove it just call `.url(:default, timestamp: false)`. Of course you can change `:default` to any other style you've defined.